# Could anyone tell me where I'm going dealing with this body response?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am writing a small plugin to send new user data to Capsule CRM via their API. I can successfully create a new 'Person' object and a new 'Task' but in order to link the 2 of them I have to do things in this order:

1. Send the Party details  to Capsule to create a new Party (done via wp_remote_post)
2. Retrieve the body of the response from that post and take the Part ID from the body
3. Send the Task details to Capsule via wp_remote_post defining the Party ID as that taken from the response of the first post.

Muy problems seem to be that I cannot get the ID from the body response of the first post so the task is continually posted without being linked to the Party it is associated to.

My plugin code is the top snippet and some example JSON for how the Party response appears is below it. Any pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks

```
// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

//Find the details of a new user

add_action('um_registration_complete', 'send_doqaru_user', 10, 2);
//add_action ('um_registration_complete' , 'doqaru_redirect_home', 10, 2);

function send_doqaru_user ($user_id){


    $new_doqaru_user = get_userdata($user_id);
    $doqaru_user_email = $new_doqaru_user -> user_email;
    $doqaru_user_phone = $new_doqaru_user -> contact_number;



    // get all the meta data of the newly registered user
    $new_user_data = get_user_meta($user_id);

    // get the first name of the user as a string
    $doqaru_user_firstname = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', true );
    $doqaru_user_lastname = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', true );



    if ($doqaru_user_email) {
        error_log ($doqaru_user_email);
    }


    if( ! $new_doqaru_user ){
        error_log( 'Unable to get userdata!' );
        return;
    } 

    $url  = 'https://api.capsulecrm.com/api/v2/parties';
    $body = array(
        'party' => array(
        'type' => 'person',
        'firstName' => $doqaru_user_firstname,
        'lastName' => $doqaru_user_lastname,
        'phoneNumbers' => array(
            array(
                'type'      => 'Work',
                'number'    => $doqaru_user_phone
                )
            ),
        'emailAddresses' => array(
            array(
            'address'       => $doqaru_user_email,
            'type'          => 'Work'

    ))));

    $args = array(
        'method'      => 'POST',
        'timeout'     => 45,
        'sslverify'   => false,
        'headers'     => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer Token goes here',
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
        ),
        'body'        => json_encode($body),
    );

    $request = wp_remote_post( $url, $args ); 

    if ( is_wp_error( $request ) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $request ) != 201 ) {
        error_log( print_r( $request, true ) );
    }

    $response = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);

    $bodyresponse = json_decode($response, true);

    $partyid = $bodyresponse ["party"]["id"];

    if ($partid) {
        error_log("the party ID is" . $partyid);
    } else {
        error_log ("Could not retrieve a Party ID");

    }


//CREATE THE NEW TASK WITH THE ID OF THE NEW USER
$taskurl = 'https://api.capsulecrm.com/api/v2/tasks';
$taskbody = array(
    "task" => array(
        "party"         => array(
            'id'        => $partyid,
            'type'      => 'person'),
        "description"   => "Follow up on new created user incase it is a lead",
        "dueOn"         => "2019-04-20"
        )
        );

$taskargs = array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'timeout'     => 45,
    'sslverify'   => false,
    'headers'     => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer token goes here',
        'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
    ),
    'body'        => json_encode($taskbody),
);

$taskrequest = wp_remote_post( $taskurl, $taskargs );


}



//REDIRECTION TO DOWNLOADS PAGE
function doqaru_redirect_home() {
    wp_redirect (home_url() . '/member-downloads');
    exit;
}
```

Ok, so I have tweaked my code a bit and if I var_dump my $body_response then I get the below assoc array. But when I error_log my $partyid it fails to find a value?

```
 array(1) {
  ["party"]=>
  array(18) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(182528177)
    ["owner"]=>
    NULL
    ["team"]=>
    NULL
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "person"
    ["about"]=>
    NULL
    ["title"]=>
    NULL
    ["firstName"]=>
    string(6) "Daniel"
    ["lastName"]=>
    string(10) "Sutherland"
    ["jobTitle"]=>
    NULL
    ["createdAt"]=>
    string(20) "2019-03-29T15:02:33Z"
    ["updatedAt"]=>
    string(20) "2019-03-29T15:02:33Z"
    ["organisation"]=>
    NULL
    ["lastContactedAt"]=>
    NULL
    ["pictureURL"]=>
    string(59) "https://facehub.appspot.com/default/person?text=DS&size=100"
    ["phoneNumbers"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(371335500)
        ["type"]=>
        string(4) "Work"
        ["number"]=>
        string(11) "07507681488"
      }
    }
    ["addresses"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["emailAddresses"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(371335501)
        ["type"]=>
        string(4) "Work"
        ["address"]=>
        string(24) "d.sutherland86@gmail.com"
      }
    }
    ["websites"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) structures your JSON. `var_dump($bodyresponse)` results in:

```
object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
  ["parties"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1 (18) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(11587)
      ["type"]=>
      string(6) "person"
      ["about"]=>
      NULL
      ["title"]=>
      NULL
      ["firstName"]=>
      string(5) "Scott"
      ["lastName"]=>
      string(6) "Spacey"
      ["jobTitle"]=>
      string(17) "Creative Director"
      ["createdAt"]=>
      string(20) "2015-09-15T10:43:23Z"
      ["updatedAt"]=>
      string(20) "2015-09-15T10:43:23Z"
      ["organisation"]=>
      NULL
      ["lastContactedAt"]=>
      NULL
      ["owner"]=>
      NULL
      ["team"]=>
      NULL
      ["addresses"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#2 (7) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(12135)
          ["type"]=>
          NULL
          ["city"]=>
          string(7) "Chicago"
          ["country"]=>
          string(13) "United States"
          ["street"]=>
          string(21) "847 North Rush Street"
          ["state"]=>
          string(2) "IL"
          ["zip"]=>
          string(5) "65629"
        }
      }
      ["phoneNumbers"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(12133)
          ["type"]=>
          NULL
          ["number"]=>
          string(12) "773-338-7786"
        }
      }
      ["websites"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["emailAddresses"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#4 (3) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(12134)
          ["type"]=>
          string(4) "Work"
          ["address"]=>
          string(22) "scott@homestyleshop.co"
        }
      }
      ["pictureURL"]=>
      string(64) "https://capsulecrm.com/theme/default/images/person_avatar_70.png"
    }
  }
}
```

The `id` you're after becomes an `int` within an `object` within an `array` within an `object`. You'll have to use object notation (`->`) to get what you're after:

```
$party_id = json_decode($bodyresponse)->parties[0]->id;
var_dump($party_id);
// Result: int(11587)
```

[<sup>Repl.it</sup>](https://repl.it/@esqew/DrabStarryFossil)

Comment: thank you for your reply. When I check error logs on running the sequence I get an error saying that json_decode is expecting a string and is recieving an array? do you know why this may happen as I thought that retrieving the body only should pass a string of json containing the body object into the variable as a PHP object or array depending on the second partameter. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @DanSutherland It's because [`wp_remote_retrieve_body()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_retrieve_body) returns an `array`. You can't pass an array to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) because it only accepts JSON-formatted strings. Do a `var_dump($response)` and post the output to the body of your question, but ultimately you'll likely need to replace `json_decode($bodyresponse)` with `$response` in this solution, with some minor tweaks depending on how WP organizes the output.

Comment: Thank you for your response @esqew I have posted the contents of $bodyresponse above in the main body of my question. I still cannot seem to extra the ID from it with my attempt topopulate the $partyid variable? any ideas?

Is it something to do with the ['party]['id'] value starting with int? Do I need to do something in order to retrieve that value?

Comment: @DanSutherland I see your new `var_dump()` output, but it doesn't look like you've changed the code you're actually using to attempt to access this structure; would you mind updating it to your latest spec? You still have `json_decode()` in there, which we discovered was unnecessary.

Comment: thanks pal, when tinkering with it I was able to var_dump the $bodyresponse after decoding with the assoc array boolean set to fale - this gave me objects, so I set it back to true (as per the code I've just updated above) and then it was returning me the arrays that i updated also.

It looks like it is possibly arrays inside an object?

Comment: Infact, that being the case then if I just return it as an object i can use object notation like you described in one of your comments above - let me try that just now. @esqew